# Apache vhost configuration for wildcard subdomain support

Tags: apache-2.4

I am having a hard time running my application (built on laravel 5.4) on a wildcard subdomain that I have setup on my local machine (running Apache 2.4.18 on Linux Mint 18.1)

So, I have setup a vhost (domain.app) and a subdomain (sub.domain.app) for it and my apache vhost file looks like the following:

```
# This is for the primary domain (domain.app)
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  domain.app

        ServerAlias www.domain.app


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/domain.app/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/test/domain.app/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

# This is for the subdomain (sub.domain.app)
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName domain.app
                VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/%0/public
                ServerAlias *.domain.app
                <Directory /var/www/html/test/sub.domain.app/public>
                        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                                Options -MultiViews
                                RewriteEngine On
                                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                                RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
                        </IfModule>
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine for all of the following urls:

- http://domain.app
- http://domain.app/login
- http://domain.app
- http://sub.domain.app/login

But since, I want a wildcard subdomain, meaning I do not want to hardcode sub.domain.app in the vhost but want something like anything.domain.app so I tried to replace

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test/sub.domain.app/public>
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test/%0/public>
```

I get the following results:

- http://domain.app (works)
- http://domain.app/login (works)
- http://domain.app (works)
- http://sub.domain.app/login (404 Not found, The requested URL /login was not found on this server.)

Please can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Replying my own question.

I finally found out the solution. I am using the following vhost config for wildcard subdomain and its working like a charm.

```
UseCanonicalName Off    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin nobody@example.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.app
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/%0/public
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm index.html

    <Directory /var/www/html/test/*.domain.app/public/>
        AllowOverride   All
    </Directory>

    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vhosts-access.log vcommon
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vhosts-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will be useful for anyone facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but I think you need to replace the path also in `<Directory /var/www/html/test/sub.domain.app/public>` directive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Like I mentioned in my initial post, i dont want to hardcode sub.domain.app since i want a wildcard subdomain, for eg xyz.domain.app or abc.domain.app should work without configuring those subdomains explicitly.

Is that possible?

Comment: Well, if Apache allows using `<Directory /var/www/html/test/%0/public>`, have you tried similar format in the directive I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I tried <Directory /var/www/html/test/sub.domain.app/public> and it works, but is there anyway so I dont have to hardcode sub.domain.app?

Comment: So did you try the `%0` format?

Comment: Yes 0% just doesn't work, the apache documentation says that it supports regex. But I m not sure how regex can help here